# Storyboard.Gettarget returned result is Null

Tags: wpf, storyboard

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
da.From = 0;
da.To = 400;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Storyboard.SetTargetName(da, "r13");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
mySubStoryBoard.Children.Add(da);
DependencyObject do =Storyboard.GetTarget(mySubStoryBoard.Children[0]);
string str = Storyboard.GetTargetName(mySubStoryBoard.Children[0]);
```

---

result : do==null,str==r13.

Why is that?Help me,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect? You set [Storyboard.SetTargetName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settargetname.aspx) and [Storyboard.SetTargetProperty Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.settargetproperty.aspx) but not [Storyboard.SetTarget Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663141.aspx).

That's why [Storyboard.GetTarget Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.gettarget.aspx) returns null.